# Xamarin.Forms GetAsync stops debugging without error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, httpclient

My MainPage code-behind:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Query().Wait();
    App.Current.MainPage = new Categories();
}

public async Task Query()
{
    restaurantsClient = (App.Current as App).restaurantsClient;

    try
    {
        var restaurantsNames = await restaurantsClient.GetCatalogsAsync(1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var x = 0;
    }
}
```

I tried this code too but didn't work, happens the same problem:

```
async static Task GetRequest(String URL)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // As soon as I try to step over (or even into) this next line, it crashes.
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL))
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Rest-API in C#:

```
var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When the project reach this line it just die without showing any error.
If I do it in the browser it works.
The API is running locally in my PC (Im using Conveyor to expose the API).

Ok I make a video to see better what Im talking about:
https://youtu.be/ONKTipPsEXI
As you can see after I click Next Step in response line stop executing the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using `.Wait()` of a `Task` on the UI thread (`Button.Clicked` event is handled on the UI thread) causing a deadlock. *The task is waiting for the UI thread to give it control and the UI thread is waiting for the task to complete*. The solution to this is to add `async` modifier to your event handler and use `await Query()` instead of `Query().Wait()`.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Query();
    App.Current.MainPage = new Categories();
}
```

I'd also recommend reading [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by **Stephen Cleary** about this matter. Moreover, he's made a fabulous series ([A Tour of Task](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html)) about C# tasks in general.

***UPDATE:***

After OP's question update and discussion in this answer's comments; he thinks that there's a problem because he can reach the end of `GetCatalogsAsync(int)` before the end of `GetCatalogsAsync(int, CancellationToken)`. That's completely natural and is to be expected. Solution:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<CatalogsInCategory> GetCatalogsAsync(int id)
{
    return await GetCatalogsAsync(id, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: The problem of Android dying is solved but the problem of reaching the response line and don't execute the rest of the code remains.

Comment: I add a video to show what is happening in the question go take a check.

Comment: @LOLJovem I watched the video. What happens when you add a break-point on the first line inside the try (`var headers_ = ...`)? is it being hit after you press `OK` in the 'Telerik is trial' dialog?

Comment: But the var headers inside the try is below the response line so is never executed because when the project reach that line dont execute more code.

Comment: By 'but' you infer that it's being hit, and then you say it's never executed. So, is it being hit or not?

Comment: The problem is when executed the response line it exit instead of keep executing. As you can see in the video when I press Next Step (F10) it exit.